# How to add Or to a where statement in the Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to Or instead of && in a where clause in the controller? 
I want the results when Status is Open to look for 'New' OR 'In Process' in m.Status. Can I do this?

Thanks, EB

Here is what I am trying:

```
where (m.Status == Status || (Status == "Open" && m.Status == "New" && m.Status == "In Process") || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Status))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translates very clearly into code:

```
Status == "Open" && (m.Status == "New" || m.Status == "In Process")
```

Is that what you are after?